# How use v-if with array length

Tags: vue.js

I want to show a div if the array length is more than `0`. I used it below.

HTML:

```
<div v-if="countfunc > 0">
  <div v-for="nhp in countfunc">
     <p v-text="nhp.code"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Vue:

```
computed: {
   countfunc: function(){
     //this return a js array
   }
}
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: `countfunc.length > 0`

Comment: @adiga Isn't that expensive, as in it calls the function twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it as `countfunc.length>0`

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, if countfunc is an empty array it will not show anything anyway, so this double check is a little bit unnecessary. Of course in your code you're forgetting the :key property in v-for as well.

Here you can try on [codepen](https://codepen.io/drocha87/pen/oNLxOJZ), try to delete the object inside the array and let it empty like

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

And you can see that not will be rendered since the array is empty.